# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException on htmlunit

Tags: java, import

//Below code to hit web page continuously .In this time we are getting the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:782)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:768)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowImpl.destroyChildren(WebWindowImpl.java:185)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowImpl.setEnclosedPage(WebWindowImpl.java:110)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:209)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
    at sample.ShareScraper.getHtmlPage(ShareScraper.java:303)
    at sample.ShareScraper.GetData(ShareScraper.java:116) Exception in getHtmlPagemethod.

```
package sample;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Vector;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableDataCell;
import com.jls.library.JLStructure;

public class ShareScraper {
    private  WebClient wc1,wc2,wc3,wc4,wc5;
    private JLStructure JLSObj = null;
    HtmlPage details_page1 = null , details_page2 = null , details_page3 = null , details_page4 = null , details_page5 = null;
    //Object[] share_values = null;
    Vector<String> share_values = null;
    public void GetData()  {
        System.out.println("it is getdata method");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JLSObj = new JLStructure();
        HtmlPage homePage = null;
        String[] share_codes1 = null , share_codes2 = null , share_codes3 = null , share_codes4 = null , share_codes5 = null;
        try{
            wc1 = new WebClient();
            wc1.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);       
            wc1.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wc1.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
            wc1.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            wc1.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            wc1.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());


            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
            homePage = wc1.getPage("http://www.google.com/finance");
            share_codes1 = new String[]{"NSE:UNITECH" , "NSE:RENUKA" , "NSE:DISHMAN" , "NSE:TATASTEEL" , "NSE:TATAMOTORS" , "NSE:NECLIFE" , "NSE:RAIN"  , "NSE:ORIENTCEM" , "NSE:JSWSTEEL" , "NSE:JINDALSTEL"};
            for (int share_code_no = 0; share_code_no < share_codes1.length; share_code_no++) {
                    String ei = homePage.getAnchorByText("Finance").getHrefAttribute();
                    ei = JLSObj.matchData("(?<=\\?ei=).*", ei);  
                    details_page1 = getHtmlPage("http://www.google.com/finance?q="+share_codes1[share_code_no]+"&ei="+ei , wc1 , 1);
                    System.out.println(share_codes1[share_code_no]);    
            }
            System.out.println("finished");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Vector<String> GetShareValues(){
        System.out.println("it is get sharae value method");
        String NSE_UNITECH = null , NSE_BAJAJHIND = null , NSE_RENUKA = null , NSE_DISHMAN = null , NSE_TATASTEEL = null , NSE_TATAMOTORS = null , NSE_RAIN = null, NSE_ORIENTCEM = null , NSE_JSWSTEEL = null ;
        try{
            synchronized(this){
                details_page1 = (HtmlPage) details_page1.refresh();
            }

            NSE_UNITECH = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:UNITECH",details_page1);
            if (NSE_UNITECH == ""){
                details_page1 = null ; details_page2 = null ; details_page3 = null ; details_page4 = null ; details_page5 = null ; wc1 = null ; wc2 = null ; wc3 = null ; wc4 = null ; wc5 = null;
                System.out.println("page is destroyed again getdata is called");
                System.gc();
                GetData();
            }

            //"NSE:UNITECH" , "NSE:RENUKA" , "NSE:DISHMAN" , "NSE:TATASTEEL" , "NSE:TATAMOTORS" , "NSE:NECLIFE" , "NSE:RAIN"  , "NSE:ORIENTCEM" , "NSE:JSWSTEEL" , "NSE:JINDALSTEL"
            //"UNITECH" , "RENUKA" , "DISHMAN" , "TATASTEEL" , "TATAMOTORS" , "RAIN" , "ORIENTCEM" , "JSWSTEEL" , "JINDALSTEL" , 
            NSE_UNITECH = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:UNITECH",details_page1);
            NSE_RENUKA = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:RENUKA",details_page1);
            NSE_DISHMAN = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:DISHMAN",details_page1);
            NSE_TATASTEEL = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:TATASTEEL",details_page1);
            NSE_TATAMOTORS = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:TATAMOTORS",details_page1);
            NSE_RAIN = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:RAIN",details_page1);
            NSE_ORIENTCEM = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:ORIENTCEM",details_page1);
            NSE_JSWSTEEL = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:JSWSTEEL",details_page1);
            NSE_JINDALSTEL = GetTableDataCellText("NSE:JINDALSTEL",details_page1);


            share_values = new Vector<String>();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            share_values.add(timeStamp);
            System.out.println("Now time is :"+timeStamp);

            //"UNITECH" , "RENUKA" , "DISHMAN" , "TATASTEEL" , "TATAMOTORS" , "RAIN" , "ORIENTCEM" , "JSWSTEEL" , "JINDALSTEL" ,
            share_values.add("UNITECH :"+NSE_UNITECH);
            share_values.add("RENUKA :"+NSE_RENUKA);
            share_values.add("DISHMAN :"+NSE_DISHMAN);
            share_values.add("TATASTEEL :"+NSE_TATASTEEL);
            share_values.add("TATAMOTORS :"+NSE_TATAMOTORS);
            share_values.add("RAIN :"+NSE_RAIN);
            share_values.add("ORIENTCEM :"+NSE_ORIENTCEM);
            share_values.add("JSWSTEEL :"+NSE_JSWSTEEL);
            share_values.add("JINDALSTEL :"+NSE_JINDALSTEL);

            //websitevpn.com
            //freevpn
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return share_values;
    }

    private String  GetTableDataCellText(String param , HtmlPage data_page) throws IOException{
        String result = null;
        HtmlTableDataCell span = null;
        HtmlPage data = null;
        if (data_page!=null){
            data = data_page;
        }
        else{
            data = details_page1;
        }

        span = ((HtmlTableDataCell) data.getFirstByXPath("//td[preceding-sibling::td[a[contains(@title ,'"+param+"')]]]"));
        if (span!= null){
            result = span.asText();     
        }else{
            result = "";
        }
        return result;  
    }

    public synchronized HtmlPage getHtmlPage(String url , WebClient webClient , int count) {
        HtmlPage result_page = null;
            try {
                result_page = webClient.getPage(url);
            } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    if (count <= 6){
                        getHtmlPage (url , webClient , count++);
                    }   

                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result_page;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebClient is not thread safe refer here:

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html

Comment: I have a page which works with htmlunit for the first time. If I edit the same page in browser directly and then try to scrape the webpage using htmlunit then I get concurrent exception. How to fix this?